# CVAT is not showing annotations externally generated on images

Tags: xml, computer-vision

I have a dataset with existing annotations, which we are using CVAT to refine and enhance.  The existing annotations are in PASCAL VOC format.  When I import the annotations in CVAT, the objects show up in the 'Objects' tab on the right, and all settings seem good, but now bounding box is drawn on the image.

To ensure that the VOC is importing correctly, I've created new annotations on the image, then exported all annotations and compared how the imported annotations look relative to the one created in CAT.  Looking at the .xml file, the boudning boxes look to be formatted identically.

As a further test, I removed all of the annotations in CVAT, and then re-imported annotations, but this time importing the CVAT XML file I exported above.  All of the bounding boxes and labels appear in the right tab, but the annotations VOC imported boxes still don't show up on the image.  The annotations from CVAT however do.  Can someone take a look at my VOC file, and my CVAT XML file and let me know if there is a setting I'm missing here?

Note that I need the bounding boxes on the image as we're doing a multi-step annotation.  Basic blob detection finds potential objects in a shot, then experts are going in and placing more specific labels, and correcting any annotation errors.

CVAT XML File

```
<annotations>
  <version>1.1</version>
  <meta>
    <task>
      <id>17</id>
      <name>test</name>
      <size>1</size>
      <mode>annotation</mode>
      <overlap>0</overlap>
      <bugtracker></bugtracker>
      <created>2019-11-03 18:48:55.796680+00:00</created>
      <updated>2019-11-03 18:50:27.480771+00:00</updated>
      <start_frame>0</start_frame>
      <stop_frame>0</stop_frame>
      <frame_filter></frame_filter>
      <z_order>False</z_order>
      <labels>
        <label>
          <name>blob</name>
          <attributes>
          </attributes>
        </label>
        <label>
          <name>bleep</name>
          <attributes>
          </attributes>
        </label>
      </labels>
      <segments>
        <segment>
          <id>17</id>
          <start>0</start>
          <stop>0</stop>
          <url>http://pacific.eightysixfour.com:8080/?id=17</url>
        </segment>
      </segments>
      <owner>
        <username>nhuntoon</username>
        <email></email>
      </owner>
      <assignee></assignee>
    </task>
    <dumped>2019-11-03 18:50:35.930589+00:00</dumped>
  </meta>
  <image id="0" name="uS-X006Y018_2_slide11_b.jpg" width="552" height="369">
    <box label="blob" occluded="0" xtl="95.00" ytl="267.00" xbr="178.00" ybr="184.00">
    </box>
    <box label="blob" occluded="0" xtl="110.65" ytl="192.52" xbr="158.87" ybr="258.27">
    </box>
    <box label="bleep" occluded="0" xtl="512.23" ytl="33.38" xbr="545.95" ybr="62.37">
    </box>
  </image>
</annotations>
```

"box label="blob" occluded="0" xtl="95.00" ytl="267.00" xbr="178.00" ybr="184.00""
doesn't show on the image

VOC XML file

````
    <folder>test</folder>
    <filename>uS-X006Y018_2_slide11_b.jpg</filename>
    <path>/home/loki/workspace/CapturedData/slide11_b/croped/test/uS-X006Y018_2_slide11_b.jpg</path>
    <source>
        <database>Unknown</database>
    </source>
    <size>
        <width>369</width>
        <height>552</height>
        <depth>3</depth>
    </size>
    <segmented>0</segmented>
    <object>
        <name>blob</name>
        <pose>Unspecified</pose>
        <truncated>0</truncated>
        <difficult>0</difficult>
        <bndbox>
            <xmin>95</xmin>
            <ymin>267</ymin>
            <xmax>178</xmax>
            <ymax>184</ymax>
        </bndbox>
    </object>
</annotation>```
````

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue.  The VOC XML file has the height and width of the source image backwards.  Changing those to the proper order makes this work as expected with no issues.